# Mycontract.deploy().send() does not work

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development

I am trying to deploy a contract with web3 1.0.0 like:

```
myContract.deploy({})
.send({
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891',
    gas: 1500000,z
    gasPrice: '20000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ ... })
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
   console.log(receipt.contractAddress) 
})
```

and I get the following error:

> Script failed: Error: Returned error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot
>   unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go struct field
>   SendTxArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes

Previously I am using the same address to get the contract, and it is in hex format(0x...).

`let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891', gas: 47000, data: bytecode});`

and it is correct. So I do not know what can be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was creating the contract:

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {from: account, gas: 47000, data: bytecode});
```

It is solved adding '0x' before the bytecode.